# How To Show Hello World with Glade/GtkD and the D Programming Language

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, d, glade, gtkd

On Ubuntu Linux, I can use the Glade application to create a Hello World dialog. Now how do I get the D programming language to display it?

Comment: if you solved this yourself, don't forget to post the answer here too (you can answer your own question) so people searching can see it too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Install the **DMD compiler** that compiles the D language on your Mac, Linux, or Windows computer. You can get more info about this [here](http://dlang.org/download.html).
2. Install the **Glade interface designer** on your Mac, Linux, or Windows computer. You can get **Glade** on Ubuntu Linux quite easy with `sudo apt-get install glade`, but more information about installing on the various other platforms is [here](https://glade.gnome.org/).
3. Install **GTKd** on your Mac, Linux, or Windows computer. This is not easy. You will need to start with the documentation at [gtkd.org](http://gtkd.org/) and then interact in the [DLang.org Learn forum](http://forum.dlang.org/group/learn) for more assistance if necessary.
4. Open **Glade** and create a new window that has a label on it saying Hello World.

> Note that the tools palette in Glade shows a **Window** widget and an **ApplicationWindow** widget. Since we're not drawing any menus, ensure you're using the **Window** widget instead of the **ApplicationWidget**. If you fail to do that, you'll get warnings when running the application, talking about some missing menu calls.

Save it as **hello.glade**.

5. Open your **hello.glade** file in a text editor and look for a line that looks similar to this:

`<object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">`

Write down on a piece of paper that **id** attribute.

6. Create a **hello.d** script in the same directory as this **hello.glade** file and alter the following contents, changing the **window1** to whatever was your **id** you wrote down earlier.

```
import gtk.Builder;
import gtk.Main;
import gtk.Widget;
import gtk.Window;
import std.stdio;

int main (string[] args)
{
    Main.init(args);
    Builder b = new Builder();
    b.addFromFile("hello.glade");
    Window w = cast(Window)b.getObject("window1");
    w.addOnHide( delegate void(Widget aux){ Main.quit(); } );
    w.showAll();
    Main.run();
    return 0;
}
```

7. Compiling is tricky. On Ubuntu Linux, I had to create a statement like the following. You may have to interact in the [dlang.org Learn forums](http://forum.dlang.org/group/learn) for your particular platform.

```
# dmd hello.d `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkd3`
```

8. Once compiled, you can run your D executable to show the Hello World dialog. On Ubuntu Linux, I simply did:

`# ./hello`

9. Note that when you see the window and close it, you may receive some warnings on Linux. (On other platforms, this may vary.) I was receiving a warning about "Couldn't connect to accessibility bus - connection refused". The fix at least on Linux is to add this to your **~/.bashrc** script at the bottom:

`export NO_AT_BRIDGE=1`

Now when you open the command prompt and run your compiled D command "hello" again,
       it will not show that error.

If you get errors regarding menus, then you used an **ApplicationWindow** widget instead of a
       **Window** widget, and will need to switch that in **Glade**.

## Adding Buttons & Signals

1. The way I do it is to click on a widget in **Glade**, click **Signals**, find the event I want to add, such as **clicked**, and then in the Handler column, type in a function. For example, on a button1, I would type **onButton1Clicked**. Save the file.
2. Now, in your D source code, right after you create your Window object, add this code:

`b.connectSignals(null);`

...where b is your Builder variable.

3. In your D source code, add a function for this signal. For instance, I did:

```
extern(C) void onButton1Clicked()
{
    writeln("got here");
    Main.quit();
}
```

Note that in this case, the extern(C) is required.

4. Recompile and run your application. You'll see that it automatically runs your new function for that button click.